# Не обновляется позиция курсора на игровом поле в консольной игре

Tags: c++, консоль

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct koo {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
};

void Cursor(int, int);

int main() {
    bool Game = true;
    while (Game == true) {
        // МАТРИЦЯ. 
        const int length = 25; // Розміри матриці.
        string mas[length + 1][length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                /* Один елемент матриці це 3 строкових елементи з клавіатури, чи букви,
                чи символи, чи пробіли.*/
                mas[i][j] = "   ";  // Заповнення пустого місця.
                mas[length - 1][j] = "###"; // Нижній рядок.
                mas[0][j] = "###"; // Верхній рядок.
                mas[i][length - 1] = "#"; // Правий стовбчик 
                mas[i][0] = "#";          //  Лівий стовбчик 
                mas[0][length - 1] = " ";
            };
        };
        // ПЕРЕШКОДИ В СЕРЕДИНІ ІГРОВОГО ПОЛЯ
                    // Вертикальні перешкоди.
                    // 2 стовбчик
        for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
            mas[i][2] = " # ";
        };
        //6 стовбчик
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            mas[i][6] = " # ";
        };
        for (int i = 15; i < 21; i++) {
            mas[i][6] = " # ";
        };
        //10 стовбчик
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
            mas[i][10] = " # ";
        };
        for (int i = 9; i < 14; i++) 
            mas[i][10] = " # ";
        };
        for (int i = 16; i < 23; i++) {
            mas[i][10] = " # ";
        };
        //15 стовбчик
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            mas[i][15] = " # ";
        };
        for (int i = 9; i < 12; i++) {
            mas[i][15] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 17; i < 24; i++) {
                mas[i][14] = " # ";
            };
            // 19 стовбчик.
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                mas[i][18] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 8; i < 14; i++) {
                mas[i][19] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 19; i < 23; i++) {
                mas[i][19] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 8; i < 20; i++) {
                mas[i][22] = " # ";
            };
            // ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНІ РЯДКИ.
                    // 2 рядок.
            for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
                mas[2][i] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 12; i < 14; i++) {
                mas[2][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 4 рядок.
            for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
                mas[4][i] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 19; i < 22; i++) {
                mas[4][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 6 рядок.
            for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
                mas[6][i] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 18; i < 24; i++) {
                mas[6][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 8 рядок.
            for (int i = 19; i < 21; i++) {
                mas[8][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 10 рядок.
            for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
                mas[10][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 13 рядок.
            for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
                mas[13][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 15 рядок.
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                mas[15][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 17 рядок.
            for (int i = 14; i < 20; i++) {
                mas[17][i] = " # ";
            };
            // 23 рядок.
            for (int i = 9; i < 11; i++) {
                mas[23][i] = " # ";
            };
            for (int i = 19; i < 23; i++) {
                mas[23][i] = " # ";
            };
    
            // ВИВІД МАТРИЦІ.
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    cout << mas[i][j];
                }
                cout << endl;
            };
```

Отрисовка игрового поля чрз двухмерную матрицу.
[image: Пример игрового поля]

```
            koo koo;

            Cursor(koo.x, koo.y); 

            char wad = _getch();
            if (wad == 'w')
            {
                koo.y = koo.y--;
                Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);
            }
            else if (wad == 'a')
            {
                koo.x = koo.x--;
                Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);
            }
            else if (wad == 'd')
            {
                koo.x = koo.x++;
                Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);
            }
            else if (wad == 's')
            {
                koo.y = koo.y++;
                Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);
            }
            else if (wad == 'q')
            {
                Game = false;
            }
            system("cls");
        };
    }
    
    /*
    Проблема з курсором, не обновляється екран. Можлива причина в неправильному розташуванні функції SYSTEM('CLS')
    */
        
    
    void Cursor(int X, int Y) {
        COORD cord;
        cord.X = X;
        cord.Y = Y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cord);
        char curs = '@';
        cout << curs;
    
    }
```

Дальше ф-я отрисовывает позицию курсора. 1 итерация с координатами {1}{1}. Дальше чрз клавиатуру изменяет структуру с Координатами koo.x или koo.y -+ 1. От чего в следующих итерациях курсор перемещается.
Проблема в том, что в последующих итерациях курсор остается на на позиции {1}{1}. Думаю. что причина может быть либо в функции, либо в выборе структуры как вместилища координат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в другом. Просто что у вас заполнение матрицы, её прорисовка, опрос и стирание экрана происходит на каждой итерации цикла. Т.е. на каждой итерации:

- создается и заполняется матрица;
- заново создается объект `koo koo;` с координатами {1}{1}
- вызывается `Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);` для вновь созданного объекта `koo` - {1}{1}
- прорисовывается поле - выводится матрица
- запрашивается ввод пользователя
- изменяются координаты в объекте `koo`
- перерисовывается курсор
- и сразу очищается экран !!!!!!!!
- и теперь удаляется `koo`, удаляется `mas[][]` !!!!!!!

Вы просто не успеваете увидеть перемещение курсора.
Нужно первичное заполнение матрицы и объявление объекта `koo` сделать до основного цикла. Вы же поле игры формируете один раз, зачем это делать в цикле? А чтобы в `koo` запоминались координаты, он должен создаваться (со значениями по-умолчанию) не на каждой итерации цикла, а один раз до цикла.
А также стирание экрана в цикле делать первой операцией, до отрисовки поля и курсора.
Должно быть как-то так:

```
int main() 
{
    // Объявление переменных
    bool Game = true;
    const int length = 25; // Розміри матриці.
    string mas[length + 1][length + 1];
    koo koo;
    
    // Первичное заполнение игрового поля
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            /* Один елемент матриці це 3 строкових елементи з клавіатури, чи букви,
            чи символи, чи пробіли.*/
            mas[i][j] = "   ";  // Заповнення пустого місця.
            mas[length - 1][j] = "###"; // Нижній рядок.
            mas[0][j] = "###"; // Верхній рядок.
            mas[i][length - 1] = "#"; // Правий стовбчик 
            mas[i][0] = "#";          //  Лівий стовбчик 
            mas[0][length - 1] = " ";
        };
    };
    Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);

    for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++)             mas[i][2] = " # ";
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)            mas[i][6] = " # ";
    for (int i = 15; i < 21; i++)           mas[i][6] = " # ";
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)             mas[i][10] = " # ";
    for (int i = 9; i < 14; i++)            mas[i][10] = " # ";
    for (int i = 16; i < 23; i++)           mas[i][10] = " # ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)             mas[i][15] = " # ";
    for (int i = 9; i < 12; i++)            mas[i][15] = " # ";
    for (int i = 17; i < 24; i++)           mas[i][14] = " # ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)             mas[i][18] = " # ";
    for (int i = 8; i < 14; i++)            mas[i][19] = " # ";
    for (int i = 19; i < 23; i++)           mas[i][19] = " # ";
    for (int i = 8; i < 20; i++)            mas[i][22] = " # ";
    for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++)             mas[2][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 12; i < 14; i++)           mas[2][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)             mas[4][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 19; i < 22; i++)           mas[4][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++)             mas[6][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 18; i < 24; i++)           mas[6][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 19; i < 21; i++)           mas[8][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++)             mas[10][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++)           mas[13][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)             mas[15][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 14; i < 20; i++)           mas[17][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 9; i < 11; i++)            mas[23][i] = " # ";
    for (int i = 19; i < 23; i++)           mas[23][i] = " # ";

    while (Game == true) 
    {
       system("cls");
            // ВИВІД МАТРИЦІ.
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) 
              cout << mas[i][j];
           cout << endl;
       };

        char wad = _getch();
        if (wad == 'w')
            koo.y--;
        else if (wad == 'a')
            koo.x--;
        else if (wad == 'd')
            koo.x++;
        else if (wad == 's')
            koo.y++;
        else if (wad == 'q')
            Game = false;
        
        Cursor(koo.x, koo.y);
    };
}
```

И `koo.y = koo.y--;` - избыточная запись, достаточно `koo.y--;`. Декремент `y--` это равносильно `y = y - 1;`.
Ещё ошибка - не проверяется выход курсора за пределы поля. Т.е. находясь по координатам [1][1] можно уйти на координаты [0][1], а потом и на [-1][1] и т.д.
Ещё лишние операции при заполнении матрицы:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            mas[i][j] = "   ";  // Заповнення пустого місця.
            mas[length - 1][j] = "###"; // Нижній рядок.
            mas[0][j] = "###"; // Верхній рядок.
        }
        // эти присваивания зависят только от i - им не нужно повторяться в цикле по j
        mas[i][length - 1] = "#"; // Правий стовбчик 
        mas[i][0] = "#";          // Лівий стовбчик 
    };
    mas[0][length - 1] = " "; // это присваивание не зависит от итераторов  i j, ему не надо быть в циклах
```

И дальше можно улучшить. Вместо двумерного массива `string mas[25][25]` лучше использовать `char mas[25][75]` - съэкономите занимаемой памяти немного и уменьшите объем кода. Или хотя бы `string mas[25]`, т.к. `string` - это по-сути массив `char`;
Также на каждой итерации стирается экран и поле игры рисуется заново. Можно один раз нарисовать поле (до цикла), а потом перерисовывать только курсор. Для этого в функцию `Cursor();` нужно добавить вывод пробела на старое место курсора, перед выводом курсора по новым координатам.
Или хотя бы перерисовывать поле не на каждой итерации, а только если произошли изменения. С другой стороны - и так работает. :)